# Codeigniter can't display image

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem. Why is the image in my code not displaying?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <!-- start grids_of_3 -->
    <?php
    $query=$this->db->get('produk');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $c) {
    ?>
    <div class="grids_of_3">
        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.php">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/$gambar')?>" alt=""/> **-> i think error in this**
                <h3><?php echo $c['nama']?></h3>
                <span ><?php echo $c['harga']?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: What's the result of debugging? Are there any errors?

Comment: What's in `$gambar` ?

Comment: no error , just image cannot display , $gambar mean variabel for display image.

Answer (score 1):

*Why is the image in my code not displaying?*

---

You should check differences between single and double quotes in PHP.

[Docs says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Make it like:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/' . $gambar)?>" alt=""/>
```

or

```
<img src='<?php echo base_url("assets/uploads/$gambar")?>' alt=""/>
```